# Double check cable and conductor type selection for remote panel

Tags: wiring

I'm not looking for help on conductor sizing here as I still have some math to do.  I am looking for confirmation that the type of cable and conductors I'm planning to use are appropriate.

Scenario is running a feeder to sub panel (with a main breaker) in detached pole building. From the house main panel branch circuit breaker I intend to run SER cable exposed in the basement floor joists to the exterior wall closest to the pole building.  I will then have an exterior disconnect with the line side being fed through the wall by the SER cable.  Between the disconnect and the pole building sub panel I will be running PVC conduit, with a portion going underground.  I'll be using XHHW-2 conductors from the load side of the disconnect to the main breaker in the sub panel.

I plan to run four conductors all the way, 2 hot, 1 neutral, 1 ground and the sub panel will also have a ground rod and the entrance to the pole building and the ground will be kept isolated from the neutral.  For the XHHW-2 section of the feeder, I intend to get different colored conductors to keep with code requirements.

The reason I'm using the disconnect is it seems to be be less bulky than a large junction box and it gives me another point to isolate if needed.

Does anyone see any concerns with the type of cables and conductors I have selected, as well as where I have called out conduit or lack there of? I did not want to run the individual conductors all the way as I did not want to run the conduit in the basement.  If someone sees a major flaw with running the SER on the first portion of the feeder,  I could run conduit the entire run and use the XHHW-2 all for the entire feeder run.

The other option I considered, but am not leaning towards is MHF cable as a continuous cable panel to panel without using the disconnect. My outdoor PVC conduit section between the house and pole building is minimal so the MHF conduit pull should not be too bad.

Thanks.

Comment: What's MHF cable?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's Mobile Home Feeder cable.   It's a multi-conductor twisted bundle like tri-plex but with 4 conductors.